# Marionette ItemView with data from two resources

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js, marionette

currently I'm fiddling around with Marionette and Backbone (because I have to). I have a list of entities: `CompositeView` with `ItemViews`, every ItemView has a model with data like `firstname` and `lastname`.

In each `ItemView` is a link that will catch new data for the ItemView via AJAX (another endpoint!) and should update the view with a list of additional data like: `[{"id": 1, "foo": "this is soo bar"}, {"id": 2, "foo": "a little bit of baz"}]`. That data should be rendered then into the view (and can be removed again on a click).

What's the best way to go here? Adding a second model within the `ItemView` or add the new data to the existing view? Or something completely different? I appreciate every helpful tip!

**My Solution** (kind of)

Here is what I ended up with: when the link for the additional data is clicked, the associated `ItemView` instanciates a `Backbone.Collection` object I defined. That collection holds the URL for the endpoint. Then, I call the `collection.fetch()` method and render that collection with Underscore like this (roughly):

```
var tpl = _.template(dataTemplate);
var html = tpl({ myData: {collection.models});

node.html(html);
```

Thank you guys for thinking with me :)

Comment: *"every ItemView has a model with data like firstname and lastname"* - Where does this data come from? an endpoint or something else?

Comment: Exactly. The App will be initiated on a button click, will call an AJAX endpoint and will then render this (JSON) data first. Edit: but that endpoint is another one

Comment: basically you cannot have multiple models for one itemview

Comment: But I could add additional data to the existing one, right? The additional data won't be synchronized or something. So maybe I will just render the data from the second call...

Comment: @Hando for that I guess https://github.com/theironcook/Backbone.ModelBinder is a good option

Comment: @nikhilmehta Thank you. That's looking interesting. I'll give it a try :)

Answer (score 0):

Bunch of different ways to solve, this is what I prefer

**Template Helpers**

```
var View = Mn.ItemView.extend({
    templateHelpers: function () {

        // Each property will be available in the template
        return {
            extraData: 'my data',
            anotherModel: this.getOption('secondModel').toJSON(),
            someOtherData: ''
        }
    }
});

new View({model: MyModel, secondModel: SecondModel});
```

To get extra data into the view from a parent, checkout `childViewOptions`

By the look of your data, its an array of items. So your `childView` for your `CompositeView` could be a `CollectionView`